# Google container Engine django deployment is raising error

Tags: django, deployment, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have set up my Django project to deploy on the container engine based on documentation https://cloud.google.com/python/django/container-engine.

After creating kubernetes resources with

```
kubectl create -f project.yaml
```

I try to get the status of the pods with

```
kubectl get pods
```

Each of the pod has status `**CrashLoopBackOff**`

Can you please suggest on debugging this error?

Comment: try `kubectl describe pods`

Comment: @Moema, what should I look at it? I shows lots of information.

Comment: can you edit your original post to include the output of the describe command?